# Typecasting in C and use of parentheses

Tags: c, casting, parentheses

I have these variables

```
distance = 945
speed = 614
```

I want to get the time in hours and minutes so I divide distance/speed in order to get the hours. Now, if I want minutes as an integer I have the following code:

```
int minutes;
minutes = (float) (distance%speed) / speed * 60;
```

This expression gives the value of 32 minutes, however, when I first tried, I wanted to make the code more "readable" and I tried the following options that gave me 0:

```
minutes = (float)  ( (distance%speed) / speed * 60 );
minutes = (float) ( (distance%speed) / speed  ) * 60;
```

Note that the parentheses are added and are in different places, so why using parentheses in places that look fine to me interfere with the calculation and sets the value of 0 in the variable. I guess it has to do with the typecasting process, but the parentheses are in places that are supposed to make clearer the expression.

I have the right answer and the program works properly but I want to understand this for future occasions because I spent a little time playing with the parentheses. Thank you

Comment: To make the code more readable, consider adding a comment to specify the units of distance and speed, or change the variable name: distance_metres, speed_metres_per_sec, etc.

Comment: Why do you expect cast to follow the distributive law? Is `1 / (2 + 3) ==  1 / 2 + 3`? That code does not make much sense either way. Your compiler should complain. Read the C info page for some very useful advise. And provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Chritian - Kingsley's comment (adding the unit) is actually very good regardless of your actual variable names.

Comment: In C++ there are better solutions using [Boost.Units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_units.html)

Comment: and don't use `float` unless it's really needed. Prefer `double` in general

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> so why using parentheses in places that look fine to me interfere with the calculation and sets the value of 0 in the variable.

That's because the extra parentheses `()` invalidates your cast to `float` in your 2nd statement.

- In your first statement:

`minutes = (float) (distance%speed) / speed * 60;`

Here `(float) (distance%speed)` is evaluated first.

- But in your 2nd statement:

`(float) ( (distance%speed) / speed * 60 );`

Your extra `()` causes `(distance%speed) / speed * 60` to be evaluated first, thus the cast `(float)` becomes irrelevant.

> I wanted to make the code more "readable"

Related to "readability", while adding more parentheses here certainly doesn't help, suggestion from Kingsley (adding the units) is a good way. For instance,

```
int distance_m = 945;
int speed_kph = 614;
```